# SAPUI5 Table Position Sum in Footer under Column Values

Tags: javascript, html, css, sapui5

I need to position the Sum of the column values under the right column. I've tried gridlayout but it seems to be not the right way. Is there a possibility to set the footer values under the columns?

My Code : [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/cepoholiqu/1/edit?html,output)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a Toolbar with a ToolbarSpacer and two Texts:

```js
new sap.m.Toolbar({
    content: [
        new sap.m.ToolbarSpacer({
            width: "33%"
        }),
        new sap.m.Text({
            text: "500",
            textAlign: "Right",
            width: "33%"
        }),
        new sap.m.Text({
            text: "1000",
            textAlign: "Right",
            width: "33%"
        })
    ]
})
```

See the [updated JSBin](http://jsbin.com/fuyezunugo/edit?html,output).

However note that this only works well as long as the Columns stay the same size and order. You can turn off resizing and reordering with table properties.

If you want to keep that behavior, I would suggest to add a Sum entry to your model instead.